# How to create Live Wallpaper application in android?

Tags: java, android, android-image

I want to create Live wallpaper in android where collection of images are play in fade in and fade out effect.
So I can show it as live wallpaper.I want wallpaper like...
[Lord Krishna live wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funnyfreelivewallpaper.krishna&feature=more_from_developer)

So please reply if any link is available or any example of live wallpaper is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the following Vogella Tutorial on how to create a Live Wallpaper, might help you out!
"http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html"
:]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code tutorial for creating live wallpaper application in android.
click [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper)

Comment: Great reference, the quickest starter I've stumbled on yet

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1345466/luke-wyatt